# Combine multiple RDDs into one by column through key

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Got an RDD problem. 
Say, I have three RDD, they are `RDD[AttribClass1]`, `RDD[AttribClass2]`, `RDD[AttriClass3]`, and each `AttribClass` has one field name as id, what I want to do is to combine all the attributes into one big RDD for the combined class, say, the class is

```
ContainerClass(id: IDClass, attrib1: AttribClass1, attrib2: AttribClass2, attrib3: AttribClass3)
```

And I want to get `RDD[ContainerClass]` by joining the ids.
I saw something similar post based on find RDD by key, but not quite exactly the same. 
[Spark RDD find by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421484/spark-rdd-find-by-key)

Does anyone have done similar thing?

What's the best way of creating new RDD without combining them locally?

Thanks,
Shi

Comment: Add some clarification:

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I think the best way to know how to do this is to look through the RDD API. This can be done through groupByKey method, and then coGroup.